# Calling a specialized template function, when there is also a non-template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

In this example, how is it possible to call the second function?

```
template<class T>
T square(T a) {
    std::cout << "using generic version to square " << a << std::endl;
    return a*a;
}

/// "int" is so special -- provide a specialized function template
template<>
int square(int a) {
    std::cout << "using specialized generic version to square " << a << std::endl;
    return a*a;
}

/// and there's one more: a non-template square function for int
int square(int a) {
    std::cout << "using explicit version to square " << a << std::endl;
    return a*a;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: I dont know what you mean, but my question may not be very meaningful for real code. I was just wondering how it would be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the specialization by explicitly specifying the template argument:

```
square<int>(2);
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c5de11e8c27b32)